# Проблема с owl-carousel 2 , не инициалезируется в спрятанном блоке

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel, карусель

Собственно вопрос таков. 
У меня есть спрятанный блок c display:none, в нём находится owl-carousel. И если загрузить страницу и скажем по клику поменять с display:none на display:block , карусель не подгружается...
Если же блоку дать изначально display: block, то всё нормально... Как возможно обойти этот глюк, кто сталкивался? Повторная инициализация $('#owl-carousel').owlCarousel() результата не даёт.
В консоли ошибок нет соответственно.

Comment: Что-то подобное было. Попробуйте инициировать карусель с небольшой задержкой после клика с помощью `setTimeout`. Если это бутстраповские табы, то там есть специальное событие - `shown.bs.tab`

Comment: Можно попробовать вместо display:none использовать opacity: 0 и overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно решение следующее, повесил событие клика на блок и в нём описал функцию инициализации - отработало верно. carousel_init блок с display:none;

```
$("#carousel_init").click(function(){
 $('#owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
 настройки...
  });
})
```